# How to set name in <form> without name:?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'd like to create a `<form>` tag like below:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/login" method="post" name="login_form">
```

As the online document in http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html says, I call form_for in templates such as:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, login_path(@conn, :index), [name: :login_form], fn form -> %>
```

but a warning occurs: `the :name option in form_for/inputs_for is deprecated, please use :as instead`

It's suppressed that replacing `name:` with `as:`, but name parameter is omitted. How to set name with as:, or other parameter?

```
<%= form_for @changeset, login_path(@conn, :index), [as: :login_form], fn form -> %>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use as workaround both keys (`:name` and `:as`) until the deprecation was removed.

The `name: tag` key set the `name="login_form"` attribute **and** set the form fields to `login_form[field_name]`.
In my opinion is that conflict the cause of change the `:name` to `:as`.

Code

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, [name: "login_form"], fn f -> %>
    <%= text_input f, :user, class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

Result

```
<form name="login_form" method="post">
    <input name="login_form[user]" type="text">
</form>
```

If you set both the `:as` tag override the field object definition from `:name`.

Code

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, [name: "login_form", as: "account"], fn f -> %>
    <%= text_input f, :user, class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

Result

```
<form name="login_form" method="post">
    <input name="account[user]" type="text">
</form>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you!  I can evade the issue with your workaround.